# sum values in row that correspond to some values in the same row

Tags: r

I have data that looks something like this:

```
test1 <- rbind(c(1,2,1,10,20,30),c(2,2,3,30,20,10),c(3,3,1,10,10,10))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    1   10   20   30
[2,]    2    2    3   30   20   10
[3,]    3    3    1   10   10   10
```

What I'm trying to do is to sum up values from column 4:6 that correspond to  the same value in 1:3, such that I get 3 new columns with the sum of values that correspond to 1,2,3

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] 
[1,]    1    2    1   10   20   30  40   20    0
[2,]    2    2    3   30   20   10   0   50   10
[3,]    3    3    1   10   10   10  10    0   20
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This returns the three columns that you can then `cbind` onto your matrix:

```
> do.call(cbind,lapply(1:3, function(c){rowSums((test1[,1:3]==c)*test1[,4:6])}))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   40   20    0
[2,]    0   50   10
[3,]   10    0   20
```

It uses an `lapply` loop but I don't see how to do it without some sort of loop short of completely unwrapping your data into a tidy format.